# Increase geojson file size limit in OAC Data Viz

Tags: oracle, geospatial, geojson

I have a full-clipped geojson file, that contains the 2019 STP boundaries for England, I need this for accuracy purposes.

However, the size of this geojson is a touch over 49mb & unfortunately, the max upload limit is 25mb when adding a custom map layer in the console of OAC.

Is there anyway to increase this limit? If so, how do I go about this?

Splitting the file isn't an option, it works, but how OAC renders the map, means that if I'm viewing data at a higher level, it will also pull through the lower level data too and that defeats the object of having filters!

Any advice would be really, really, appreciated! Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't increase the size limit for custom map layers (GeoJSON files) in OAC.

You could raise a SR to Oracle and ask them to do it, but don't expect too much from that.

As an alternative, I suggest to simplify your GeoJSON file in order to fit the 25 MB limit. You can try using a free tool such as [Mapshaper](https://mapshaper.org) to do it